# Trying to find intersection of 3 functions graphically

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the following 3 functions:

- $f_1 = 3x-cos(yz)-0.5= 0$
- $f_2 = x^{2}-81(y+0.1)^{2}+sin(z)+1.06  = 0$
- $f_3 = e^{-xy}+20z+ \frac{10\pi-3}{3} = 0$

  ```
  Show[ContourPlot3D[{3*x - cos[x*y] - 0.5 == 0, x^2 - 81*(y + 0.1)^2 +
  sin[z]    + 1.06 == 0,Exp[-x*y] + 20*z + ((10*Pi - 3)/3) == 0 }, 
  {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50,50},{z, -50, 50},
  ContourStyle -> {{Purple, Opacity[0.8]}, {Green, Opacity[0.8]}, 
  {Orange, Opacity[0.8]}}]]
  ```

but it gives me a error.  How do I fix this?  Also is there any way to show graphically where the 3 functions intersect, say with a red dot or something?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi; You have some syntax errors in there cos(x) should be Cos[x*y] same thing with sin(z), should be Sin[z].

Comment: that's the error i get

Comment: Change that pi to Pi also.

Comment: still getting errors

Comment: You have to learn to format code for your questions so that people can just copy and paste. That way you get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I got this working, this may not be an answer. It is just a cleanup of your code.

```
ContourPlot3D[{3 x - Cos[x*y] - 1/2 == 0, 
  x^2 - 81 (y + 1/10)^2 + Sin[z] + 106/100 == 0, 
  Exp[-x *y] + 20 z + (1/3) (10 \[Pi] - 3) == 0}, {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Purple, Opacity[0.8]}, {Green, 
    Opacity[0.8]}, {Orange, Opacity[0.8]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: i was using the code button and typing it in idk why it was not writing it like it should anyway i don't get why you say it may not be the answer?

Comment: For one thing on my machine 3D graphics are a bit clunky so I shortened everything from -50 to 50 to -10 to 10.

Comment: That's okay I just wanted to see where they intersect

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: I am not much help but your welcome.